# Python Algorithm To Maximize Number of Equal Elements in List

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list

I am trying to make an algorithm in Python that will take a list of random numbers from 0 to a 1,000,000 no more than 100 elements in length and will even this array out as much as possible giving me the maximum number of equal elements. This is what I have so far:

```
def answer(x):
    diff = max(x) - min(x)
    while diff > 1:
        x[x.index(max(x))] = x[x.index(max(x))] - (diff / 2)
        x[x.index(min(x))] = x[x.index(min(x))] + (diff / 2)
        diff = max(x) - min(x)
    return count(x)

def count(x):
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(x)
    return max(c.values())
```

This will take an array such as [0,50] and create an array [25,25] and return the integer 2 because there are two equal elements in the array. I know for a fact this algorithm works in most cases however it doesn't in all.
Can anyone please point out any array of integers this would not yield the correct answer for? Thanks

### Edit:

For those who don't want to read the while loop the code finding the range of the entire list. Splitting the range in half and adding half to the min, and subtracting half from the max. It is trying to equalize the entire list while keeping the same sum

[1,4,1] = [2,3,1] = [2,2,2] = (number of equal elements) `3`
[2,1,4,9] = [2,5,4,5] = [3,4,4,5] = [4,4,4,4] = (number of equal elements) all`4`

Comment: If you already know that it doesn't always work, why do you need us to tell you when it doesn't always work?

Comment: I just know on some tests where I don't know what the array is, it fails I don't know which conditions make it fail that is all I know

Comment: you want 100 random numbers in range 0-1m and want to find maximum equal ones?

Comment: I don't get it. You're trying to replace all the numbers in the array by the array's mean? (That's what [0,50] -> [25,25] suggests to me)

Comment: Yes if you read the information in the while loop that is apparent

Comment: Wouldn't `the maximum number of equal elements` be an array of all `1`s, of length equal to the size of the given interval?

Comment: its 1/1000 chances, possible equal elements. Which is very rarely you can find equal ones.Also you can just use random.randint and a simple for loop for that.

Comment: Not after you distribute the difference between max and min which is what the while loop is doing.

Comment: Are you trying to rescale your data to within an interval of [0,1] from the mean?

Comment: I still dont get it. What is the problem actually. You can put them to a list and check if there is equal numbers or not.

Comment: My original description was unclear but I thought the code would help. However I added a revised description

Comment: An example or two of your input and expected output would help.  Just the one `[0,50]` isn't enough.

Comment: Could you show us an example where not all the numbers in the answer are the same?

Answer (score 4):

What about this?

```
l = [1, 2, 5, 10]

# "best" possible case
l_m = [sum(l) / len(l)] * len(l)

# see if lists fit (division can cause rounding errors)

if sum(l_m) != sum(l):
    # if they don't this means we can only have len(l) - 1 similar items
    print len(l) - 1
else:
    # if sums fit the first list can be spread like this
    print len(l)
```

Comment: Nice one, can also do:
`l = [1, 2, 5, 10]; s = sum(l); ave = s / len(l); print len(l) - (s != ave * len(l))`

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine that you're trying to make as many elements in the array equal as possible, while keeping their sum, and keeping the elements *integer*.

For `N` elements, you can get `N - 1` elements equal, and, with some luck, all `N` equal.

This is a bit of pseudocode for you:

```
average = sum(elements) / length(elements)  # a float
best_approximation = trunc(average)  # round() would also work
discrepancy = sum(elements) - best_approximation * length(elements)
discrepant_value = best_approximation + discrepancy
result = [discrepant_value] + the rest of list having best_approximation value
```

By construction, you get `length(elements) - 1` of equal values and one `discrepant_value`.

Comment: Yes for N elements I can get n-1 equal and with some lists N equal. For example a list of [1,2,3,4,5,7] will get returned with [4,3,3,4,4,4]. Now to actually maximize the list equality I need to increase the minimum by 1, and decrease the new minimum by 1. This will give me n-1 elements equal I think this should work if I implement it correctly

Comment: You don't need to care about minimum and maximum at all. You _throw away_ the original values. All you care about is their sum and average, and the rounding error which is represented by `discrepancy`. For `[1 2 3 4 5 7]` you can get `[6 3 3 3 3 3]` or `[2 4 4 4 4 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really doing in normalizing your input to an integer average and distributing the remainder among the result.

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,7]

# Calc the integer average
avg = sum(L)/len(L)

# Find the remainder
mod = sum(L)%len(L)

# Create a new list length of original
# populating it first with the average
L2 = [avg] * len(L)

# Then add 1 to each element for as many
# as the remainder
for n in range(mod): L2[n] += 1

def count(x):
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(x)
    return max(c.values())
count(L2)
4
```

You don't need to morph the original list or create a new one (negating the need for your `import`):

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,7]

# Don't even need to figure the average if you
# find the remainder of the sum of your list
# divided by the length of your list
mod = sum(L)%len(L)

result = mod if mod >= len(L)/2 else len(L) - mod
print result
4
```

Comment: While Python is well readable, I think this answer an be improved by an actual explanation of the process.

Answer (score 0):

## This is the final solution I have come to.

After it minimizes the entire array's range to no greater than 1, it then checks to see if the number of equal numbers in the array is the same as the length, this means the array looks something like this: `[4,4,4,4]` then spit out the number of equal numbers immediately (4). If the number of the majority of the equal numbers in the list is less than the length then it equalizes the list. So if the list is something like `[4,4,3,3]` it is more optimal if it could be turned into `[4,4,4,2]`. This is what the equalize function can do.

```
def answer(x):
    diff = max(x) - min(x)
    while diff > 1:
        x[x.index(max(x))] = x[x.index(max(x))] - (diff / 2)
        x[x.index(min(x))] = x[x.index(min(x))] + (diff / 2)
        diff = max(x) - min(x)
    print(x)
    if count(x) == len(x):
        return count(x)
    return equalize(x)    

def equalize(x):
    from collections import Counter
    eq = Counter(x)
    eq = min(eq.values())
    operations = eq - 1
    for i in range(0,operations):
        x[x.index(min(x))] = x[x.index(min(x))] + 1
    return count(x)

def count(x):
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter(x)
    return max(c.values())
```

## http://repl.it/6bA/1